# Uncaught TypeError: this.noticeContainer is null

Tags: javascript, wordpress

revise por favor, mis portfolios han dejado de verse:
http://www.baroniarialb.cat/portfolio-items/la-rectoria-de-la-torra/

Veo el siguiente error de consola, necesitaría orientacion para resolverlo.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.noticeContainer is null
init http://www.baroniarialb.cat/wp/wp-content/plugins/cookie-notice/js/front.min.js?ver=2.1.0:1
<anonymous> http://www.baroniarialb.cat/wp/wp-content/plugins/cookie-notice/js/front.min.js?ver=2.1.0:1
front.min.js:1:6860
init http://www.baroniarialb.cat/wp/wp-content/plugins/cookie-notice/js/front.min.js?ver=2.1.0:1
<anonymous> http://www.baroniarialb.cat/wp/wp-content/plugins/cookie-notice/js/front.min.js?ver=2.1.0:1
```

El contenido existe en el editor pero no se visualiza online ni tampoco en el editor live.
Ya he inhabilitado / habilitado todos los complementos y he vaciado el caché y los enlaces permanentes. ¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando? Uso el tema AVADA y Wordpress 5.7

Comment: Si ya ha testeado los plugins y temas y sigue pasando algo mas debe de estar causando el error, con tan poca información es imposible dar una buena asesoría, le recomiendo mejor contratar a un desarrollador para que solucione su problema.

Comment: Qué tipo de información adicional necesito brindar?

Comment: Solo con lo que ha mostrado es muy difícil saber que lo esta causando, yo me atrevería a decir que es el tema, haga una copia en local o en otra carpeta, desactive el tema y ponga uno por defecto, verifique si le funciona, si es así, es el tema el que lo provoca, luego de eso será realizar pruebas hasta encontrar el error, sin embargo si no tiene mucho conocimiento sobre ello se le dificultara el solucionarlo.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho amigo, he cambiado de tema pero el constructor que es el Fusion Builder necesita AVADA, sino no funciona con otros temas. También he bajado una versión anterior de Wordpresss a la 5.7 pero sigue sin mostrarse el portfolio.

Comment: Lamento oír eso, en ese caso, contrate un desarrollador, nosotros no podemos saber que es con tan poca información, hay un universo de cosas que podrían fallar, lo mejor será que contrate a un experto en wordpress para que realice testing en su sitio hasta encontrar el error en el tema.